# .htpasswd / .htaccess is letting *almost* any password work

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess

I set up .htaccess / .htpassword and It works, except when I type the password incorrectly it still logs me in.. If I use a completely different password, doesn't work. A different user name, it doesn't work.

But if I use the proper user name and *mostly* the right password, it works?

Example:

password I'm using is "firefight", and "firefighter" seems to work. "Hose" won't.

Any clue?

Comment: Please show the htaccess and htpasswd files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [htpasswd page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html):

> When using the `crypt()` algorithm, note that only the first 8 characters of the password are used to form the password. If the supplied password is longer, the extra characters will be silently discarded.

Comment: This is something i never knew about crypt, +1

Answer (score 3):

Only the first 8 characters are taken into consideration.